# How to convert cups to an upstart job?

Tags: 10.04, printing, upstart

I'm having some issues with cups on 10.04 (64 bit).

I'm running about 200+ machines with the same image and cups crashes a lot.

What I'd like to do is create an upstart job to monitor and respawn cupsd if it crashes. I've tried to find the solution myself but I'm struggling.

Can anyone provide some help?

Kind regards,
Darknomel

Comment: Have you tried using the `respawn` command in `/etc/init/cups.conf`? http://netsplit.com/2008/04/19/upstart-05-job-lifetime/

Comment: At the moment, cups is started out of /etc/init.d/cups , there is no job in /etc/init/ - is there an update to upstart or cups that I need to do for it to create the upstart job or can I create it manually?

Comment: Hmm, sorry, I forgot to check, cupsd start was migrated to upstart for maverick, not lucid. You can try copying the `/etc/init.d/cups` and `/etc/init/cups.conf` from maverick, but I don't know if it will work (the changelog is pretty big ;).

Comment: Cool, I'll get ye old maverick iso out and see what I can do. Thanks!

Comment: The upstart job from maverick should work fine.. I'm interested to find out if that works. If it does, make sure to give arrange credit (arrange, you really should put that in as an answer instead of a comment)